# Wordpress query posts with thumbnail images and recent post titles

Tags: wordpress

i am beginner to wordpress theme development.I am developing a theme.I am going through a problem.

In my index.php page i want the most latest post displayed as thumbnail.The second,third and fourth latest post is displayed with only title.I also have five categories.I want the posts displayed category wise.

Now how to do that.Can anyone help me???

Answer (score 0):

Please review the wordpress query before creating a theme first : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query . With regards to the question. Try this :

```
// The Query
$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 5);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$count = 0;
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        if($count == 0){
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }else{
            echo get_the_title();
        }

        $count++;
    }
        echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks.But if i have the different categories suppose,Home,First Blog, Second Blog, third Blog etc and i want the posts according to category then how can i edit the query.

Answer (score 0):

Please test with this code:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&cat=18');
$count = 0;
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        if($count == 0){?>

            <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>



                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( '%s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                                    <?php the_title();  ?>
                                </a>

    <?php
        }else{ ?>
           <li class="list">

                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( '%s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                                    <?php the_title();  ?>
                                </a>
                        </li>

            <?php
        }

        $count++;
         echo "</li>";
    endwhile;

} else {
    echo "No Post Found!";
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```